# How to get a selection of different crosses

Tags: fonts

I'm wondering if Latex has some kind of cross package where I can get different kinds of crosses.  I know how to get one with option+t = †.  Are there others that I can get?

Thank you.

Comment: If you use `luatex` or `xetex`, you can use any font containing the crosses you want, e.g., [FleurCross](https://p22.com/family-FleurCross) (commercial) or [SacredOldSymbols](http://luc.devroye.org/klein.html) (free, after Rudolf Koch).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend consulting The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, housed on CTAN at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive and searching internally for "cross." This will find both symbol names and command names that include "cross." That's important because some symbols don't necessarily contain that name (for example `\dagger`). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  That's helpful.